# Extending user model is causing an HTTP 400 error

Tags: django

I followed the `Django` documentation to try to extend my user model to add a field called `authentication_key`. It is resulting in an `HTTP 400` error when I test the site locally.

My models:

```
class AuthenticationKey(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    authentication_key = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

My Admin:

```
class AuthenticationKeyInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = AuthenticationKey
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'AuthenticationKey'

# Defines a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (AuthenticationKeyInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

And how I'm referring to the field in my `views.py`

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def home_page(request):
    u_id = request.user.authenticationkey
    url = "http://example.com/api/allrequests/?format=json"
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    j_data = json.loads(data)
    j_data = json.dumps(j_data)

    url = "http://example.com/api/past24hrdialoguebyid/" + str(u_id) + "/?format=json"
    response = urlopen(url)
    m_data = response.read().decode("utf-8")

    return render(request,'index.html',{"u_id":u_id,"j_data":str(data),"m_data":str(m_data)});
```

I'm thinking the error may be how I'm referring to the field in `views` but I can't figure out quite what's wrong.

Here are my URL Patters:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', home_page),
    path('public/', public),
    path('room-queue/', room_queue),
    path('all-requests/', all_requests),
    path('add-data/', add_data),
    path('room-api/', room_api),
    path('delete-data/', delete_data),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='admin/login.html')),
    path('index-add-guest/', add_guest),
    path('send-reply/', send_reply),
    path('room-ready/', room_ready),
]
```

Comment: could you provide more details on the `urlpatterns`?

Comment: @briancaffey I added them

Comment: OK, well your `home_page()` view function is not complete as you have it there. It needs to return a template. something like: `return render(request, 'home/home_page.html', context}`. Can you show us the rest of that function if you have written it?

Comment: @briancaffey didn't realize that was relevant, it's been added

Comment: Also, this page worked correctly before I implemented the user model extension. I had been using `u_id = request.user.id` in place of `u_id = request.user.authenticationkey`

Comment: everything seems fine, I'm just trying to find what might be causing the 404. is there a difference between accessing the urls `home` and `home/`?

Comment: It’s a 400 not 404

Comment: Perhaps it’s something outside of what I’ve posted. I’ll investigate further on my end.

Comment: What is u_id supposed to be? the authentication key? or the database ID of the user?

Comment: transitioning it from the database id of the user to the authentication key

Comment: `request.user.authenticationkey` does not exist, since you have not defined authenticationkey as a property of the User model.

if you want `authenticationkey` to be a property of user then you have to extend the User model by subclassing `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`.

Comment: @KevinL. How do you subclass the AbstractUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.user.authenticationkey` does not exist, since you have not defined `authenticationkey` as a property of the `User` model.

As already defined in your code, you should access the authentication key this way:

```
from .models import AuthenticationKey

authkey = AuthenticationKey.objects.get(user=request.user) 
u_id = authkey.authentication_key
```

if you want to access authenticationkey as a property of `user` then you have to extend the User model by [subclassing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`.

For instance, in your models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    authenticationkey = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In settings.py file, update the AUTH_USER_MODEL

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appname.models.User'
```

make sure you apply the migrations. You should then be able to access

```
request.user.authenticationkey
```

remember to update your admin too

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```